# Does Login For StackOverflow also carry over for Programmers.Stackexchange?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am logged in at stackoverflow, I switch over to here, does not appear to retain my login info?

Need separate account?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the same openid that's linked to one of your other accounts the platform will recognize it and give you the opportunity to link the accounts together.

Answer (score 1):

This should go in meta, but yes, you need a separate account for every sub-site on the stack exchange network. (they can be linked though)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll set up another account then.